# Behavior difference between TIMESTAMP and DATE

Tags: mysql, date, datetime

I have a table that has two TIMESTAMP columns (Creation_Date and Edit_date) that auto fill on INSERT (both columns get CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) and UPDATE (only the Edit_date column is changed)

The action is done by this code:

> ... `CreationDate` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
>   `EditDate` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE
>   CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, ...

I need to change the type from TIMESTAMP to DATE and have tried:

```
...
`CREATED_DATE` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
`EDITED_DATE` date NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE ON UPDATE CURRENT_DATE,
...
```

How can I get the same behavior. Any responses would be appreciated.

Comment: Which version of MySQL? Before v5.6.5, only TIMESTAMP columns can be automatically initialized and updated to the current date and time, and it's still always with `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` not `CURRENT_DATE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No its not possible unless you are using mysql 5.6.5
The only option was available until 5.6.5 is to use field type as timestamp and then set a default which is not constant.

> The DEFAULT value clause in a data type specification indicates a
>   default value for a column. With one exception, the default value must
>   be a constant; it cannot be a function or an expression. This means,
>   for example, that you cannot set the default for a date column to be
>   the value of a function such as NOW() or CURRENT_DATE. The exception
>   is that you can specify CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as the default for a
>   TIMESTAMP

If you are using mysql 5.6.5 then you can set this behaviour for DATETIME datatype

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/timestamp-initialization.html